# how to convert string format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can I convert a number to a formatted string of fixed length in SQL Server 2005 using T-SQL?

e.g.

```
Inputs: 5,01,007,0009,00011,01200
Result: 000005,000007,000009,0000011,001200
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want it 6 wide. Try putting your pad characters, in this case, zeros, to the left of your int/string, and then take the 6 chars on the right side of the string.

How about this?

```
DECLARE @i int;
SELECT @i = 1200;
SELECT RIGHT('000000'+ CAST(@i as varchar(10)), 6);
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way I've found to do this is using the `STR` statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(123, 6), ' ', '0')
```

The above statement will result in `000123`.  It basically converts 123 to a string of 6 characters (padded with spaces), then uses `REPLACE` to replace the spaces with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
WITH t(c) AS
(
SELECT 1.99 UNION ALL 
SELECT 21.34  UNION ALL 
SELECT 1797.94  UNION ALL 
SELECT 300.36  UNION ALL 
SELECT 21.99  UNION ALL 
SELECT -2.31    
)

select 
c,

replicate(0,4-len(replace(substring(cast(c as varchar(10)),1,charindex('.',c)-1),'-','')))+''+
replace(replace(substring(cast(c as varchar(10)),1,charindex('.',c)-1),'-',''),'','-') +''+
replace(substring(cast(c as varchar(10)),charindex('.',c),len(c)),'-','')

from t
```

**i will still optimize it**

Answer (score 0):

**Best way for dynamic leading zero allocation**

> WITH t(c) AS ( SELECT 1.99 UNION ALL 
>   SELECT 21.34  UNION ALL  SELECT
>   1797.94  UNION ALL  SELECT 300.36  UNION ALL  SELECT 21.99  UNION ALL 
>   SELECT 2.31    ),
>
> Final (a,b,c,d) as ( Select c,
>   substring(cast(c as
>   varchar(10)),1,charindex('.',c)-1) ,
>   (select max(len(substring(cast(c as
>   varchar(10)),1,charindex('.',c)-1)))
>   from t),  substring(cast(c as
>   varchar(10)),charindex('.',c)+1,len(c))
>   From t  group by c )
>
> select  a,
>   right(replicate('0',c)+''+b,4)+'.'+d
>   from final

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i int
set @i=10
print replace(str(@i),' ','0')
```